# Need to save NSmutableArray of PathDrawingInfo objects to be used when app is reloaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

in my application I have a NSmutableArray that contains PathDrawingInfo items. I am looking for a way to save this array for later use. The application draws the PathDrawingInfo items when any event happens, so the paths are constantly redrawn. I need to save this array of paths so it can be used with the application at a later point. The array needs to be saved with a title as well so that the user can select a previous drawing to load, modify and resave.

I have been searching for ways to do this and found that a lot of people to save their arrays for use in the application at another time - they usually convert the array to a property list. I also noticed that this only seems to work with NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSData, NSNumber, and NSDate types. Since my items are PathDrawingInfo type, I was not sure of another method to do this. Thank you for your help as I am new to objective c.

Comment: You may need to investigate NSValue. This allows the wrapping of scalar and struct types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an archiver to save the array:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.myMutableArray toFile:savePath];
```

And when you want to get it back:

```
self.myMutableArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:savePath];
```

Comment: PathDrawingInfo has three items to it, the path, the strokeColor and the fillColor. Will I have to do anything for each of these individually? or just perform this on the mutable array that has the objects in it?